# Snort rules or snort local rules?

Tags: rules, snort

What is the difference between snort rules and snort local rules ?

sudo nano /etc/snort/rules

sudo nano /etc/snort/rules/local.rules

Which one I should use for writing snort rules ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are writing your own, use local.rules

The official ruleset from Snort.org is the place to get the rest.